# GetEnumerator for Implementing IDictionary

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a `LinkedHashMap` to use as a pool for a VB.NET app, and I'm expanding by composition instead of by inheritance because a lot of the dictionary methods are not declared virtual.

How am I supposed to handle this:

```
Public NotInheritable Class LinkedDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
    Implements IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue), 

    Private ReadOnly maxCapacity As Integer
    Private ReadOnly dictionary As New Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)()
    Private ReadOnly queue As New Queue(Of TKey, TValue)()

    ' ...

    Public Sub Add(ByVal key As TKey, ByVal value As TValue) _
    Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)).Add
        dictionary.Add(key, value)
        queue.Enqueue(key)
        If queue.Count() > maxCapacity Then
            dictionary.Remove(queue.Dequeue())
        End If
    End Sub

    ' ...

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)) _
    Implements IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)).GetEnumerator
        Return dictionary.GetEnumerator()
    End Function

    Public Function GetEnumerator2() As System.Collections.IEnumerator _
    Implements System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
         Return dictionary.GetEnumerator() 
         ' ??? there's only one GetEnumerator Method in Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
    End Function

End Class
```

How does the regular dictionary class handle this implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ever want to check out how something in the .NET framework is implemented, you can simply take a look at [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com).  For instance, here's the [code for the Dictionary class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0).  If the code you are looking for isn't hosted on Reference Source, you can also use one of the many .NET decompilers to take a look at the source of any of the .NET Framework libraries (such as the free [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)).

To answer your question more specifically, as Reference Source shows, the implementation of the `GetEnumerator` method in the `Dictionary` class is as follows:

```cs
public Enumerator GetEnumerator() {
    return new Enumerator(this, Enumerator.KeyValuePair);
}

IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator() {
    return new Enumerator(this, Enumerator.KeyValuePair);
}
```

The former is the implementation for `IDictionary.GetEnumerator`, and the latter is the implementation for `IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue).GetEnumerator`.  So, all it does is create a new `Enumerator` class (which is a nested class declared inside of the `Dictionary` class), giving itself as the source dictionary argument.

It's a bit long, but here's the code for that nested `Enumerator` class:

```cs
[Serializable]
public struct Enumerator: IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>,
        IDictionaryEnumerator
    {
        private Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary;
        private int version;
        private int index;
        private KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> current;
        private int getEnumeratorRetType;  // What should Enumerator.Current return?

        internal const int DictEntry = 1;
        internal const int KeyValuePair = 2;

        internal Enumerator(Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary, int getEnumeratorRetType) {
            this.dictionary = dictionary;
            version = dictionary.version;
            index = 0;
            this.getEnumeratorRetType = getEnumeratorRetType;
            current = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>();
        }

        public bool MoveNext() {
            if (version != dictionary.version) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
            }

            // Use unsigned comparison since we set index to dictionary.count+1 when the enumeration ends.
            // dictionary.count+1 could be negative if dictionary.count is Int32.MaxValue
            while ((uint)index < (uint)dictionary.count) {
                if (dictionary.entries[index].hashCode >= 0) {
                    current = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(dictionary.entries[index].key, dictionary.entries[index].value);
                    index++;
                    return true;
                }
                index++;
            }

            index = dictionary.count + 1;
            current = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>();
            return false;
        }

        public KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> Current {
            get { return current; }
        }

        public void Dispose() {
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current {
            get { 
                if( index == 0 || (index == dictionary.count + 1)) {
                    ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumOpCantHappen);                        
                }      

                if (getEnumeratorRetType == DictEntry) {
                    return new System.Collections.DictionaryEntry(current.Key, current.Value);
                } else {
                    return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(current.Key, current.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        void IEnumerator.Reset() {
            if (version != dictionary.version) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
            }

            index = 0;
            current = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>();    
        }

        DictionaryEntry IDictionaryEnumerator.Entry {
            get { 
                if( index == 0 || (index == dictionary.count + 1)) {
                     ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumOpCantHappen);                        
                }                        

                return new DictionaryEntry(current.Key, current.Value); 
            }
        }

        object IDictionaryEnumerator.Key {
            get { 
                if( index == 0 || (index == dictionary.count + 1)) {
                     ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumOpCantHappen);                        
                }                        

                return current.Key; 
            }
        }

        object IDictionaryEnumerator.Value {
            get { 
                if( index == 0 || (index == dictionary.count + 1)) {
                     ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumOpCantHappen);                        
                }                        

                return current.Value; 
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, since the `Enumerator` class is nested inside of the `Dictionary` class, it has access to, and makes use of, some of the dictionary's private members such as `version` and `entries` to which you don't normally have access from the outside.

Comment: Great resource! I think that the thing that's a bit confusing here is how VB.NET's interface implementations are set up... `public Enumerator GetEnumerator()` in C# is the public method exposed to handle GetEnumerator. They also have another signature: `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()` which is the one that handles the IEnumerable interface. This would be `private GetEnumerator() Handles IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)).GetEnumerator` in VB.NET, but that's only callable when the reference is `IEnumerable(Of [Type])`.

Comment: Ah.  Right.  I missed that.  Since it's implementing both `IDictionary` and `IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`, it actually implements the `GetEnumerator` method twice (once for each interface).  I updated my answer to reflect that.  Thanks for pointing that out.  On a side note, mostly I far prefer C# to VB.NET, but interface implementation syntax is one of those few things that I think is better in VB.NET.  I like the more explicit syntax in VB.NET when saying which method implements what.

Comment: I'm on the same page! VB.NET is just so verbose.